# The best way to register all derived Python classes implementing one

Tags: python

The following code tries to solve the question asked, but the pattern presented does that in a not very clean way.

```
class Command(object):
    __COMMANDS = {}
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __init__(cls, name, parents, dct):
            for parent in parents:
                if hasattr(parent, '_Command__COMMANDS'):
                    getattr(parent, '_Command__COMMANDS')[cls.NAME] = cls
            type.__init__(cls, name, parents, dct)

    @classmethod
    def find(cls, command_name):
        """ Returns the Command implementation for a specific command name."""
        return cls.__COMMANDS[command_name]


class Foo(Command):
    NAME = 'foo'
```

Because of derived classes uses also the same `__metaclass__` of the parent class, this pattern can be used to register all derived classes testing if the parent class has the attribute `_Command__COMMANDS`.

This pattern could get few controversial from other people, such as:

1) The Command by it self also uses the metaclass, but because of its parent is the `type` class and it has not the `_Command__COMMANDS` attribute it works fine.

2) Use the attribute testing leaves a dirty code. The use of functions like `type` or `isinstance` are not allowed but these would be more clear than the pattern used.

Does somebody a good recommendation to improve that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply ask a class for a list of all its subclasses, by using the [`class.__subclasses__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__subclasses__#class.__subclasses__):

```
>>> class Command(object):
...     pass
...
>>> class Foo(Command):
...     NAME = 'foo'
...
>>> Command.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.Foo'>]
>>> Command.__subclasses__()[0].NAME
'foo'
```

You can use this method to implement your `find()` class method:

```
@classmethod
def find(cls, command_name):
    """Returns the Command implementation for a specific command name."""
    try:
        return next(c for c in cls.__subclasses__() if c.NAME == command_name)
    except StopIteration:
        raise KeyError(command_name)
```

or, if you expect to only call `find()` after all command subclasses have been imported, you can cache the results in a [`weakref.WeakValueDictionary()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary) (to avoid circular reference issues):

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

class Command(object):
    @classmethod
    def find(cls, command_name):
        """Returns the Command implementation for a specific command name."""
        try:
            mapping = cls.__COMMANDS
        except AttributeError:
            mapping = cls.__COMMANDS = WeakValueDictionary({
                c.NAME: c for c in cls.__subclasses__()})
        return mapping[command_name]
```

You can always clear the cache again by explicitly deleting the `Command._Command__COMMANDS` class attribute.

Comment: Nice, i didn't know about __subclasses__ attribute.